# Buttons without Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, button, tabs, uinavigationcontroller

I've almost completed my app, I created all the views and the functions, but I still have a problem with the buttons. I'd like that when I push a button, the view changes to another. To do this, I've Ctrl+Cliked the button and I've dragged the blue bar to the view I wish to appear. When the black box pops up, I choose "Segue - Push". But when I run my application for testing, when I click on the button, the App crashes and in "All Output" I see the error message "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'" My application is tab-based, so is it possible to navigate trough the views without the Navigation Controller only using the Storyboard (without writing a lot of code)? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you found out, you can't use a push -- a push segue is only for controllers embedded in a navigation controller (the fact that you don't know this, tells me that you haven't studied the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" or the "View Controller Catalog for iOS" documents -- you really should) . You can use modal segues without a navigation controller, and of course you can navigate using the tabs, but what is the right way to do with your app depends on your structure. You need to provide a little more information on what view controllers you're trying to navigate between. Are you talking about two or more controllers you want to navigate to from the same tab?

Comment: I'm new to Xcode, I have a lot of things to learn. However, my app has a Tab Bar Controller with four items. Every item is a View Conroller. In one of them, I need to insert a button that, once pushed, changes the view to another page (View Controller) that should be without the Tab Bar. I hope you understand me; if not, I'll attach you a screenshot. Thanks (:

Comment: You basically have 2 choices. You can present that view controller modally (with presentViewController:animated:) or you can embed the one with the button in a navigation controller, so that you can then push to this other page.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain step-by-step the first option (using "presentViewController:animated:") please?

Comment: @CrazySoftware, I could, but I'm not going to. You should read the documents I referenced in my answer. Presenting a view controller is very, very basic stuff -- if you don't know how to do that, then you need to read the docs. If you can't figure it out after reading them, then come back with a specific question.

Comment: Now I've read the View Controller Catalog for iOS, but I can't understand why I get the error 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController' again. ):

Comment: @CrazySoftware, Did you embed your controller in a navigatation controller? I thought you were going to do a modal presentation. If so, then you need to change the segue type to modal instead of push.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Using the "modal segue" it works. But I've only a question: why when I press the "Back" button (I've inserted one in the second ViewController to return on the first ViewController), the "Tab bar" of the first ViewController disappears? I can't explain this. O_o

Comment: I don't know what your final configuration is -- do you have a navigation bar in SecondViewController? Are you using a navigation controller at all?

Comment: No, I'm using only the tab bar controller without navigation bars and navigation controllers.

Comment: @CrazySoftware, Then where is the back button? Is it just a regular button in your view? Is second view controller the one you did the modal segue to?

Comment: The back button (it is just a regular button connected with the First View Controller with "Segue - Modal") is in the second view controller. Into this controller, I have a photogallery. In the First View Controller there are a tab bar and seven regular buttons. Every button is refers (with "Segue - Modal") to other seven View Controllers. Is it clear now? If not I'll post a screenshot. Thank you again.

Comment: To go back to a controller that presented another controller, you don't do another modal segue, you call [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; Put that line in an action method for your back button, and get rid of the segue.